# What is the best oil to use on a 3306 engine in Africa?

Tags: oil

What is the best oil type prefer to use on a 3306 Engine in Africa?

Comment: Who makes the 3306? What does the manual tell you for an oil grade?

Comment: Its a very vague question what type of vehicle 3306 is ?

Comment: @DhKo - Hopefully you saw the tags and read the answer already posted.

Comment: @Paulster2 yes I can see them.I was not able to see them a while ago maybe some network issue at my end.

Answer (score 1):

There are few variants used on Caterpillar machines. NA and T. 
They take up to 7~7.3 gallons of engine oil in 15W40 grade. Some people even use 20W50 and say it keeps the pistons good. Use CJ-4 and above standard synthetic fluid.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but you forget the TA variant (Turbocharger-Aftercooler). [**Caterpillar**](https://www.allmand.com/content/dam/allmand/na/en_us/files/support/CAT_Diesel_Engine_Fluid_Specifications.pdf) recommends 15W-40 oil (theirs, of course) for the 3306 engines. I agree with your assessment about synthetic oils. They will work best with the least amount of problems in the African heat.